# Jmeter- If response assertion fails go to loop controller and restart the transactions

Tags: jmeter

In the below snapshot if select category response assertion fails, how do i goto loop controller and continue the loop.. until the mentioned required no.of count in loop controller

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with the Loop Controller, the maximum you could do is:

1. Check whether previous Sampler is successful or not using [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and `JMeterThread.last_sample_ok` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)
2. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as a child of the If Controller and configure it to "Go to next iteration of Current Loop"

   [image]

However this way you cannot avoid incrementing the count of the Loop Controller and if/when you run out of iterations JMeter will exit the loop (unless it's something you're looking for), this way you can only skip Samplers which are below the failing one in the Loop Controller.

Maybe it worth considering going for the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter) instead.